# How can I prevent the theming layer being loaded for JSON requests?

Tags: 7, views, ajax

I can verify that `views-exposed-filter.tpl.php` is being loaded for basic JSON endpoints that don't re-render any form fields: My autocomplete -  [/search_api_autocomplete/search_api_views_flc_biz_search/-/farm](https://www.federallabs.org/index.php?q=search_api_autocomplete/search_api_views_flc_biz_search/-/farm) - is driven by the View below against Solr, and I'm using [project/ajax_facets](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_facets) to POST to 
`/ajax/ajax_facets/refresh` for filtering by other indexed fields.

[image: my view]

This breakpoint confirms i'm still loading unnecessary templates during json API calls. I haven't yet dove into the stack trace or scattered more breakpoints to find what is actually loading this, but know that could take many hours to drill down.

[image: runtime stack trace]

For huge performance improvements, *how can I avoid all of D7's theming layer when making any requests for JSON*?